# Change the value of a sum in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

I'm doing a query to obtain the numbers of people for a Christmas dinner.
The people include the workers and their relatives. The relatives are stored in a different table.

Children and adults eat a different menu and we organize tables by families.

I'm already using this query

```
select worker_name,
count(*) as total_per_family,
SUM(CASE WHEN age <  18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as children,
SUM(CASE WHEN age >= 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as adults
from
(
  /*subquery*/
)
group by worker_name
order by worker_name;
```

This query returns the number of child and adults related to the worker and count gives me the total.

The problem is that I need to add the worker to the *adults* sum.

Is there a way to modify *adults*? Either setting its initial value to 1 or adding 1 after the sum is done but before the count is obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying your query to read

```
SUM(CASE WHEN AGE>=18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 1 as adults
```

would probably be a first approach. The aggregate SUM() would be computed first, with 1 added thereafter as your initial suggestion indicated.

Comment: Thak you. This partially works. I also need to add the "+1" to the count.